# RunScheduledTask and return the result

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, scheduling

I created a task that removes itself when an external variable x,is changed:

```
x = 0;
deltatime = 2;
datatable = {}
RunScheduledTask[
   x++; 
   If[
     x >= 6, 
     Beep[]; RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask]; datatable, 
     AppendTo[datatable, x]
   ], 
  deltatime];
```

When variable `x` reaches value `x = 6`, I want to see the completed `datatable`, but this does not occur; the `datatable`  can be seen in other cell.

Why I cannot display datatable  in the same cell with `RunScheduledTask`?

It is possible to send the `Print` messages eventually included in `RunScheduledTask` directly to notebook and not to `MessageWindow`?

Answer (score 1):

`RunScheduledTask` returns only a `ScheduledTaskObject`. You are sending things to the Kernel to be done and if you want them to be printed to your notebook you have to say so.

- You can use `Print` and if you want it to print to the notebook you have to change `Edit/Preferences/Messages/Print -> Print to input notebook`.
- You can use `NotebookWrite`, but we have to inject your notebook reference to `ScheduledTask`, they are `HoldAll` and without that `Kernel` won't know anything about something like `EvaluationNotebook[]`:

  ```
  x = 0;
  deltatime = 2;
  datatable = {}
  RunScheduledTask[
      x++;
      If[
        x >= 6
        ,
        Beep[]; RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask];
        NotebookWrite[#, ToBoxes@datatable]
        ,
        AppendTo[datatable, x]],
      deltatime
     ] &@EvaluationNotebook[];
  ```
- You can also play with `Echo` and `EchoFunction` in 10.3+